# Ember: How do I find handlebars partial in the directory?

Tags: ember.js

I am playing around with Ember.js (within Rails app) and got the the point when displaying a form. I used "partial" handlebars tag, like this:

```
{{partial "entity_edit_fields"}}
```

Ember tries to retrieve the template from `_entity_edit_fields.hbs` file. However, I have put all templates related to entity into separate directory. Now, I'd like to tell Ember to look to `entity/_edit_fields.hbs`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To include the template `entity/_edit_fields.hbs` as a partial use:

```
{{partial "entity/edit_fields"}}
```

If you get stuck on something like this again, try having a look at the ember test suite. There will almost always be an example there that can help answer your question. I wasn't sure how partial worked either, so before answering I had a look at [handlebars_test.js](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/tests/handlebars_test.js#L2267)

```
test("should render other slash-separated templates using the {{partial}} helper", function() {
  Ember.TEMPLATES["child/_subTemplate"] = Ember.Handlebars.compile("sub-template");

  view = Ember.View.create({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('This {{partial "child/subTemplate"}} is pretty great.')
  });

  Ember.run(function() {
    view.appendTo('#qunit-fixture');
  });

  equal(Ember.$.trim(view.$().text()), "This sub-template is pretty great.");
});
```

Comment: i am not seeing anything filesystem related in this example. i also had a look at the stuff in Ember's github account, specifically the tests you've mentioned. i also do not see any filesystem stuff in those tests. so i am confused as to how any files are loaded from a folder.

Comment: This question wasn't really about the filesystem, it was about how the `{{partial}}` helper works. Ember does not load files - that might be done by sprockets (in a rails app) or maybe something like requirejs.